# IndexError: tuple index out of range when using two tuples grouped together

Tags: python

I'm trying to access the second tuple in a combination of two:

I don't know much about python so I'm not entirely sure if this is how it's done correctly. I've tried treating it as a dataframe but that hasn't worked either.

```
geodata = kwargs.get("geodata", ((0,0),(0,0)))
        self.from_bus_x_coord.setText(str(geodata[0]))
        self.from_bus_y_coord.setText(str(geodata[1]))
        self.to_bus_x_coord.setText(str(geodata[2]))
        self.to_bus_y_coord.setText(str(geodata[3]))
```

I get the following error: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: What are you passing to the kwarg `geodata` ? because the `dict.get` function returns the value of the index (first arg) or the default value (second arg).
I assume you pass a tuple with less than 4 values as `geodata`.
Also, the default value has only 2 values (which, they, have 2 values each).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your geodata looks like this

```
geodata = ((0,0), (0,0))
```

you got a 2-Tuple of 2-Tuples. To access a single value you first need to access the element of the outer 2-Tuple and then the element of the inner 2-Tuple like this

```
print(geodata[0][0])
```

If you try to access the 3rd or 4th element like so

```
print(geodata[3])
```

your actually try to access the 3rd or 4th element of the 2-Tuple, which in fact does not exist resulting in the tuple index out of range error